# How to ensure that accessing a buffer is private when index is set private

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

Let's say I have the following function that uses openmp:

```
void fun (){

#pragma omp parallel private(i, x, m, d0, d1)
    {
        int m;
        #pragma omp for
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            d0 = calc_dist();
            d1 = calc_dist();
            x = ((d0 < d1) ? 0 : 1);

            for (m = 0; m < 2; ++m)
            {
                buffer1[m] = i*x + m;
            }


            #pragma omp atomic update
            group_size[x] += 1;


        } 

    }
}
```

As you see, I made the variable `m` private. In this case, I am wondering if the update of `buffer1` in the line `buffer1[m] = i*x + m` is also private giving that `m` is private, or it is actually updated by all threads atomically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your code is incorrect.

`buffer1` is shared, as I strongly emphasized in your other question. You must ensure that each thread only works on exclusive indices of `buffer1`. Having a private `m` does not matter because multiple private `m` instances can and will have the same value.

You must otherwise protect the access to `buffer1`, which could be done either through `atomic` directives or with an `ordered directive`. Which way you need to go depends on your specific algorithm.